# Word Frequencies in Python

Tags: python

> Write a program that reads a sentence. The program then prints a table of word frequencies. The words are in alphabetical order with the number of times each word occurs. The words are case insensitive. The program has a word_frequencies(words) function that takes string input. It builds a word frequency dictionary from the input words string and returns the dictionary of word frequencies.

```
def word_frequencies(words):
# Implement the word_frequencies function.  The words function parameter is a string.
# Your solution here
    freq = {}
    for word in words:
        freq[word] = words.count(word)
    return freq

# The main program.  Do not change it.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = input("Enter a sentence: ")
    your_dictionary = word_frequencies(words)
    sorted_keys = sorted(your_dictionary.keys())
    for key in sorted_keys:
        print(key + ': ' + str(your_dictionary[key]))
```

This is the code I have but it's returning the frequencies for letters and spaces, not words when entering in ZyBooks now zyBooks later zyBooks forever

```
 : 5
B: 3
Z: 1
a: 1
e: 3
f: 1
k: 3
l: 1
n: 1
o: 8
r: 3
s: 3
t: 1
v: 1
w: 1
y: 3
z: 2
```

Comment: You need to split the `words` input: `for word in words.split():`

Comment: While you are at it, use `freq[word]=freq.get(word, 0)+1` as a counter... That eliminates the potential of `O(n**n)` complexity of nested loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

def word_frequencies(words):
 
    return  Counter(words.split(" "))

 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = input("Enter a sentence: ")
    your_dictionary = word_frequencies(words)
    sorted_keys = sorted(your_dictionary.keys())
    for key in sorted_keys:
        print(key + ': ' + str(your_dictionary[key]))
```

Output:

```
Enter a sentence: hi hi hi hello hello df
df: 1
hello: 2
hi: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

when using a for loop and the .count() method, we should iterate over a `set` of the words list. this avoids duplicated and unnecessary calls of the .count() method.

```
def word_frequencies(words):
    freq = {}
    words = words.split()
    for word in set(words):
        freq[word] = words.count(word)
    return freq

# The main program.  Do not change it.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = input("Enter a sentence: ")
    your_dictionary = word_frequencies(words)
    sorted_keys = sorted(your_dictionary.keys())
    for key in sorted_keys:
        print(key + ': ' + str(your_dictionary[key]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `for word in words.split(" "):`

Like:

```
def word_frequencies(words):
# Implement the word_frequencies function.  The words function parameter is a string.
# Your solution here
    freq = {}
    for word in words.split(" "):
        freq[word] = words.count(word)
    return freq

# The main program.  Do not change it.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = input("Enter a sentence: ")
    your_dictionary = word_frequencies(words)
    sorted_keys = sorted(your_dictionary.keys())
    for key in sorted_keys:
        print(key + ': ' + str(your_dictionary[key]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `split()` the input into list of words. And you can also use dict comprehension:

```
def word_frequencies(words):
# Implement the word_frequencies function.  The words function parameter is a string.
# Your solution here
     return {word: words.count(word) for word in words.split()}
```